# How do i create a job in jenkins to start and stop the Azure VMs

Tags: azure, jenkins, virtual-machine, instance

I m trying to create a Jenkins job to start and stop the Azure VMs.Thing is like whenever I trigger a (Start)job in Jenkins that job needs to start the particular Azure VM and if I trigger a (Stop) job that needs to stop the particular Azure VM.So that I need not give Azure portal access to a developer if he needs to start/stop the Azure VM, all he needs to do is triggering the Jenkins job

Comment: you can use az cli\azure powershell to achieve that

Answer (score 1):

You can write a small PowerShell script that does the job and that gets triggered whenever being executed.

Sign in with PowerShell as explained in the Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azps-2.8.0

Then **start**/stop a vm:

```
PS> Start-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroupVM" -Name "myVM"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this API call to do so

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/start